# How to copy contents of a variable?

Tags: python

I'd coding up a Sudoku solver and ran into a problem when converting a string in an appropriate Sudoku board.

An example input is "2.3.8....8..7...........1...6.5.7...4......3....1............82.5....6...1......."
which tells the user what numbers should go into a square in a Sudoku board. The '.' or '0' stands for a blank which I fill the spot in the list with the list [1,2,...,8,9]. This is done by the **transform** function. It is done correctly the first time the function is called, but for the second and third times, it is done incorrectly (seems like the new board stores some information from the previous one).

In this coding example the second print function prints incorrectly, between the first two 8's there is a 6 in the list that I print which shouldn't be there, and it is my belief that it comes from the previous transform call on the "easy_board".

Please take a look. Thanks.

```
print "Welcome to 9X9 Sudoku in Python"
SIZE = 81
LENGTH = 9

empty_board = [[i for i in xrange(1, LENGTH + 1)] for j in xrange(0, SIZE)]

def transform(input):
    if len(input) != SIZE:
        print "Input length [%d] is not of the correct size [%d]." % len(input), SIZE
        return
    board = empty_board
    for i in xrange(SIZE):
        if input[i] != '0' and input[i] != '.':
            board[i] = [int(input[i])]
    return board

easy_board = "003020600900305001001806400008102900700000008006708200002609500800203009005010300"
medium_board = "2.3.8....8..7...........1...6.5.7...4......3....1............82.5....6...1......."
hard_board = ".6.5.4.3.1...9...8.........9...5...6.4.6.2.7.7...4...5.........4...8...1.5.2.3.4."

print "\ndoing ez board"
our_board = transform(easy_board)
print our_board

print "\ndoing medium board"
our_board = transform(medium_board)
print our_board

print "\ndoing hard board"
our_board = transform(hard_board)
print our_board
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is quite correct! The problem lies in the line

```
board = empty_board
```

In python, most things are pass-by-reference, which means that this line is simply declaring the variable `board` to be a pointer to the array `empty_board`. When you then modify `board` later in your `transform` function, you're actually modifying your `empty_board`!

What you want is to *copy* `empty_board` into `board`, which you can easily do by adding an `import copy` to the top of your file and then:

```
board = copy.deepcopy(empty_board)
```

Note that you must use `deepcopy` rather than just copy, as `empty_board` is an array *of arrays*. If you just copied it, you'd get a new array containing *the same arrays*, and thus when you modified the contents of your new array you'd also be modifying the contents of `empty_board`.

Comment: 1: "In python, most things are pass-by-reference": regardless of where you come down on the appropriate label for Python's object model (if I had to pick a phrase it might be 'pass by reference value'), saying "most things" makes it seem like sometimes Python behaves in one way and sometimes in another.  But Python passes objects the same way, every time.  I'd just strip the "In python, most things are pass-by-reference" phrase.  2: lists, not arrays. :-)